# How can I add new list items on field input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

I am working on a simple to-do app.

I would like to add a new element after user clicks on enter in the input box, and nothing happen. I tried lot of ways, I will share the recent code. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

UPDATE: It finally works.
UPDATE: It finally works.
UPDATE: It finally works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Input - creating a new element //


  $(':input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && $('#text').val().length != 0) {
      var input = ($this).val()

      $('.elements').append('<div class="text-box"></div>');

      // i would like to add other elements inside a div, but i need to first get it work. // 

    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <img src="img/bg-desktop-dark.jpg" alt="background">
</header>

<section>
  <div class="container section-content">

    <div class="headline">
      <h1>TODO</h1>
      <img src="img/icon-sun.svg" class="switcher" alt="switcher">
    </div>

    <div class="create">

      <p class="circle"></p>
      <form><input type="text" placeholder="Create a new todo" id="text"></form>
    </div>

    <div class="elements">

      <div class="text-box">
        <p class="circle"><img class="img-inactive" src="img/icon-check.svg"></p>
        <p class="text">Vytvořit todo appku</p>
      </div>

      <div class="text-box">
        <p class="circle"><img class="img-inactive" src="img/icon-check.svg"></p>
        <p class="text">Vytvořit todo appku</p>
      </div>

      <div class="text-box">
        <p class="circle"><img class="img-inactive" src="img/icon-check.svg"></p>
        <p class="text">Vytvořit todo appku</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p class="items-left">5 items left</p>
      <div class="functions">
        <p class="all">All</p>
        <p class="active">Active</p>
        <p class="completed">Completed</p>
      </div>
      <p class="clear">Clear completed</p>


    </div>

  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close, a few things to make this work are:

1. You are using a `<form>` tag which will (by default) try to submit a form on enter. If you aren't sending anything to a server you can just remove this html tag
2. `($this)` should be `$(this)` because you want to use the jquery constructor to create a jquery object from the `this` context.
3. You are just appending an empty div which you won't see on the screen. You have to add the `input` text to the body of the div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Input - creating a new element //


  $(':input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && $('#text').val().length != 0) {
      var input = $(this).val()

      $('.elements').append(`<div class="text-box">${input}</div>`);

      // i would like to add other elements inside a div, but i need to first get it work. // 

    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <img src="img/bg-desktop-dark.jpg" alt="background">
</header>

<section>
  <div class="container section-content">

    <div class="headline">
      <h1>TODO</h1>
      <img src="img/icon-sun.svg" class="switcher" alt="switcher">
    </div>

    <div class="create">

      <p class="circle"></p>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Create a new todo" id="text">
    </div>

    <div class="elements">

      <div class="text-box">
        <p class="circle"><img class="img-inactive" src="img/icon-check.svg"></p>
        <p class="text">Vytvořit todo appku</p>
      </div>

      <div class="text-box">
        <p class="circle"><img class="img-inactive" src="img/icon-check.svg"></p>
        <p class="text">Vytvořit todo appku</p>
      </div>

      <div class="text-box">
        <p class="circle"><img class="img-inactive" src="img/icon-check.svg"></p>
        <p class="text">Vytvořit todo appku</p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="bottom">
      <p class="items-left">5 items left</p>
      <div class="functions">
        <p class="all">All</p>
        <p class="active">Active</p>
        <p class="completed">Completed</p>
      </div>
      <p class="clear">Clear completed</p>


    </div>

  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thanks for correction. Somehow it doesnt pull data from input. I tried also this:
var data = $(this).val()
var newElement = 
            $('.elements').append
            ('<div class="text-box"><p class="circle"><img class="img-inactive" src="img/icon-check.svg"></p><p class="text">`+ data +`</p></div>');

Comment: no problem. Your quotes are off. You need to end the string before putting the `data` variable in there, then append the rest of the string. `var newElement = $('.elements').append('<div class="text-box"><p class="circle"><img class="img-inactive" src="img/icon-check.svg"></p><p class="text">' + data + '</p></div>');`